# How to extract function attributes given a IMethodMessage?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got an IMethodMessage instance for a function that's being called. I want to find out the list of function attributes for the function. Is there any way to do this? I see that I can extract method name and typename from the IMethodMessage instance, but I can't quite figure out how to get the function attributes.

For example, if I have the following function:

```
[Steve()] 
public void enterUsername(String username) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

How can I find out if the function being called has the "Steve()" attribute?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "function attributes"? A sample would be helpful...

Comment: The function in question is declared using an attribute, like so:             "[Steve()] public void enterUsername(String username) { ... }". I want to find out if the function being called has the "Steve()" attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`IMethodMessage.MethodBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.imethodmessage.methodbase.aspx) property, then call [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) to get the attributes for the method.